# Function of SOH, LOH, POH in SONET

Tags: networking, cisco, sonet

Can anyone explain what is the function of section overhead, line overhead and path overhead in SONET STS-1 frame? Why they are used?

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 2):

Cisco has a [SONET graphical overview page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk482/tk607/technologies_tech_note09186a0080124afa.shtml) that has what you want; see Tables 7 & 8 at the bottom of the page.